# set up root password aws instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, password, ssh-keys

I need to set the password for root user when sudo su -, ubuntu user should login via ssh key only.

```
#ssh -i server.pem ubuntu@example.com

ubuntu@example.com:~$ sudo su - --> should prompt the password of root

root@example.com:~#   --> and also I have setup the password for root, but it does not prompt the password.


root@example.com:/etc/sudoers.d# cat 90-cloud-init-users 
# Created by cloud-init v. 0.7.5 on Mon, 12 Sep 2016 10:23:06 +0000

# User rules for ubuntu
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

# User rules for ubuntu
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

# User rules for ubuntu
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: [You already asked this question](https://serverfault.com/q/854191/153161).  If you are not satisfied with the answers you received, please clarify the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the settings for `ubuntu` user in `sudoers` file like this:

```
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

When you're logged in with `ubuntu` user and do a `sudo -i`, you will get prompted for the password of `ubuntu` user.

If you do `su`, you will get prompted for `root`'s password.

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-76:~$ sudo su -
root@ip-172-31-35-76:~#